# Madhusudana Saraswati on Chaitanya Mahaprabhu

Tags: avatars, advaita, chaitanya, achintya-bheda-abheda

Madhusudhan Saraswati, the author of the famous work, Advaitasiddhi was a Vaishnava belonging to the Shankarite sect. A great devotee of Shri Krishna, he is said to have been initially against Advaita but later accepted it to be the highest truth. It is often said that he was highly influenced by Sri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu in his early days.

So my questions are:

• Did he accept Chaitanya Mahaprabhu to be an incarnation of Krishna?

• What was his opinion of Mahaprabhu's Achintya Bheda Abheda philosophy?

Comment: madhusudana converted from vaishnavism to advaita - meaning, he embraced advaita after having spent time on pure vaishnavism. So while he may respect vaishnava saints, his core philosophy is advaita. This advaitin vaishnava classification is new. What is it.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury in advaita vedanta no vishnu or krishna at absolute level

Comment: @RakeshJoshi I am aware of it.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi But there is Krishna and Vishnu at relative level. Advaita state can only be experienced in Samadhi but when you are on relative plane, i.e, aware of world, God with forms is real and you can still be a devotee of Krishna or Vishnu or Shiva or Rama or Shakti.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria only if such planes are mentioned in vedas itself

Comment: @RakeshJoshi So you think there is no such thing as world? What plane do you think the universe belongs to in that case?

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria yes there are no planes like Pratibhasika etc. They exist only in the commentary of Sankara. World is real a child to his parents.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Dream is real as long as you are dreaming, world is real as long as you are aware of it. Waves are temporary but they are real for the time being.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria this is philosophy of Buddha not Hinduism. Vedas and upanishad clearly say that Brahman created world and entered it. He was not in a dream nor is jagat

Comment: @RakeshJoshi That's what I am saying, Brahman created world which is why it is real and which is why Vishnu and Krishna exists.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria the concept of dream etc is non vedic philosophy

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Dream is given as an illustration to make someone understand that universe is like a wave on ocean, it has no independent existence of its own as it depends on ocean (Brahman) and yet it is not unreal as it does exist albeit temporarily.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria its not an illustration but an athiest or nihilist approach. Non independent or non premenant does not mean unreal. They too are real.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Who said they are unreal? Read Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna or Complete Works of Swami Vivekananda to know what Advaita is.

Comment: @Chinmay Sarupria We are really fortunate that we had Adi Shankara and Sri Ramakrishna.They together clear all the doubts.Sri Ramakrishna is really a phenomenon!

Comment: @Rakesh Joshi see what is the definition of real in shatasloki of shankara. He says real=unchangeable. So is this world changing or not?

Comment: @ShripadRJoshi changing doesn't mean unreal. At least in the dictionary. There are other words for that

Comment: @Rakesh Joshi  according to you is this world  as true as Brahman?

Comment: As the tradition would have it,  Madhusūdana Sarasvatī was a great admirer of Caitanya but there is no mention of him in any of his works. Nor does he indicate any adherence to the special theology of the Caitanya-school. Nevertheless, as part of the intellectual milieu of his time, he must have known Caitanya’s life and activities. Madhusudana’s description of a Vaiṣṇava devotee who has achieved a devotee’s goal that is, the state of constant enjoyment of ecstatic devotion for Kr̥ṣṇa reminds one strongly of the traditional picture of Caitanya in constant ecstasy.